# webpack PurgeCSS webpack Plugin not working as expected

Tags: javascript, webpack, vmware-clarity

I want to purge unused CSS from the Clarity UI CSS file, in a setup using webpack and purgecss-webpack-plugin.
However, while the size of the CSS file is reduced from 565kB to 172kB, it should be reduced to 0kB since I don't use any of it. If I do the same thing using Bootstrap, the filesize is reduced to 1kB.

Why is that behaviour and is there a fix?

My folder structure is as follows:

```
|-dist  
|  
|-node_modules  
|  
|-src  
  |--index.js  
|  
|.babelrc  
|package.json  
|webpack.config.js
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-clarity",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./index.js",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@clr/ui": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");
const glob = require("glob");
const PurgeCSSPlugin = require("purgecss-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    filename: "main.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin(), new TerserPlugin()],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: "[name].css" }),
    new PurgeCSSPlugin({
      paths: glob.sync("./src/**/*.js", { nodir: true }),
    }),
  ],
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [   
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {"modules": false}
    ]
  ]
}
```

index.js

```
import "../node_modules/@clr/ui/clr-ui.min.css";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

Comment: You meant you did not have any template files such as html/js which are using these css selectors?

Comment: Yes, they are never used, only imported. These are all the files I use the reproduce the behaviour.

Comment: It looks like I know how this `purgecss` works. As you specify this `paths: glob.sync("./src/**/*.js", { nodir: true }) ` it will scan all your js files to find the selectors in your files even if your code is commented. Can you share your repo then I can help to point out where causes the issue?

Comment: That is not true. Commented code is not used by webpack/purgeCSS, I tested that. I have no repo, so if you want to give it a try you'll have to rebuild it yourself. All necessary code is provided in my question.

Comment: I don’t know how did you test but I did try by leaving the index file with only css imported from node modules. Then I tried to print out file that purgecss scans. It scans the glob you given in the config then it would append selectors which has been commented out. Then I removed all the commented content then it works as expected :) Try yourself mate

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late with this answer, but maybe it will help.

**TLDR**:
PurgeCSS only removes unused CSS classes by default. We need to enable PurgeCSS to also remove unused CSS variables, keyframes & font-face declarations.

Add the following options for PurgeCSSPlugin:

```js
{
  paths: glob.sync("./src/**/*.js", { nodir: true }),

  // add the following options
  fontFace: true,
  variables: true,
  keyframes: true,
}
```

---

**Details**:

Considering that in `src/index.js` we only import Clarity UI CSS file:

```js
import "../node_modules/@clr/ui/clr-ui.min.css";
```

let's take a look at the compiled CSS file (`dist/[name].css])`. It has ~175 kb and it contains:

- *CSS variables* defined in Clarity UI Framework
- animation declarations (*keyframes*)
- *@font-face* `font-family: "Metropolis"` declarations with the font source inlined as a base64 string

To make PurgeCSS to also remove unused CSS variables, keyframes & font-face declarations, we need to add the following options:

```js
new PurgeCSSPlugin({
  paths: glob.sync("./src/**/*.js", { nodir: true }),

  // add the following options
  fontFace: true,
  variables: true,
  keyframes: true,
}),
```

The compiled CSS file now has ~117kb.

Since the `html` and `body` tags have set a font declaration in ClarityUI CSS file, PurgeCSS will not remove *@font-face* declarations:

```css
html {
font-family:Metropolis,"Avenir Next","Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif;
font-family:var(--clr-font, Metropolis, "Avenir Next", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif);
}
```

Tested with:

```
"@clr/ui": "^4.0.16"
"webpack": "^5.89.0",
"purgecss-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
```

---

From the PurgeCSS [docs](https://purgecss.com/configuration.html#options):

> - fontFace (default: false)

If there are any unused @font-face rules in your css, you can remove them by setting the fontFace option to true.

> - keyframes (default: false)

If you are using a CSS animation library such as animate.css, you can remove unused keyframes by setting the keyframes option to true.

> - variables (default: false)

If you are using Custom Properties (CSS variables), or a library using them such as Bootstrap, you can remove unused CSS variables by setting the variables option to true.